# Controlling serialization format of a KeyValuePair<DateTime, long>'s key

Tags: json, json.net, asp.net-web-api

I am attempting to get the [Newtonsoft JSON Library](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx), bundled with WebAPI in .NET 4.5, to properly serialize the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {
    [Required]
    public DateTime DateToBeSerialized { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Dictionary<DateTime, long> DatesDict { get; set; }
}
```

After serialization, the following JSON is output:

```
"DateToBeSerialized": "2013-03-07T19:03:22.5432182Z",
"DatesDict": {
    "12/01/2012 00:00:00": 593,
    "01/01/2013 00:00:00": 691,
    "02/01/2013 00:00:00": 174,
    "03/01/2013 00:00:00": 467
}
```

As you can see, the Serializer honors the *format* of my `DateTime` when the object is of *type* `DateTime`, but fails to do so when serializing the key-portion of a `KeyValuePair<DateTime, long>`.

In other words, I'd like the serializer to output:

```
"DateToBeSerialized": "2013-03-07T19:03:22.5432182Z",
"DatesDict": {
    "2012-12-01T00:00:00.0000000Z": 593,
    "2013-01-01T00:00:00.0000000Z": 691,
    "2013-02-01T00:00:00.0000000Z": 174,
    "2013-03-01T00:00:00.0000000Z": 467
}
```

I would love any suggestions the community can provide for how to resolve this issue.

Comment: The **DateTime** key value you add to **DatesDict** is not exact the date time format you want.

Answer (score 0):

This was corrected in JSON.Net [5.0 release 1](http://json.codeplex.com/releases/view/104679) (Apr 7, 2013).  If you update to the [latest version](http://json.codeplex.com/), you should be all set.

Here is the test code I used to verify:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.DateToBeSerialized = new DateTime(2013, 3, 7, 19, 3, 22, 543, DateTimeKind.Utc);
sc.DatesDict = new Dictionary<DateTime, long>();
sc.DatesDict.Add(new DateTime(2012, 12, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, DateTimeKind.Utc), 593);
sc.DatesDict.Add(new DateTime(2013, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 2, DateTimeKind.Utc), 691);
sc.DatesDict.Add(new DateTime(2013, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, DateTimeKind.Utc), 174);
sc.DatesDict.Add(new DateTime(2013, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 4, DateTimeKind.Utc), 467);

string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sc, Formatting.Indented);
Console.WriteLine(json);
```

Output:

```
{
  "DateToBeSerialized": "2013-03-07T19:03:22.543Z",
  "DatesDict": {
    "2012-12-01T00:00:00.001Z": 593,
    "2013-01-01T00:00:00.002Z": 691,
    "2013-02-01T00:00:00.003Z": 174,
    "2013-03-01T00:00:00.004Z": 467
  }
}
```